# killing a child process (after fork) once its execution is done

Tags: c++

I m writing a simple web server. The program in simplified form is as follows

```
while(1)
{
     // accepting the connection.
     accept();

     pid = fork();

     if(pid == 0)
     { 
          // performing some operations
          _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

     } else {

          sleep(1);
     }
}
```

So once the child process executes it should terminate, and the parent process should continue accepting the connection. But, for me the child process is not getting terminated and even it(child) is also accepting the connections. Am I doing any mistake here.

I am able to see the process (child) not being killed using.

```
top -U <username>
```

I need help on this. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to spawn a new process for each connection? For a web server, I suggest using non-blocking I/O (with e.g. libev or libuv) instead.

Comment: @Aardvark Yes, i m spawning a new process for every connection..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parent process has to call [`wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/wait.html) to "reap" the child process.

The reasons you need to "wait" for the children is because there are still resources left after a process exits, for the exit code of the child process. What `wait` (and its sibling system calls) are doing is not only waiting for child processes to end, but also get the exit code so the child process can be cleaned up properly by the operating system. If the parent process doesn't wait for all child processes to exit before itself exits, then all child processes becomes orphaned, and the process with process id `1` is set as their parent.

Comment: so i need to wait for child process to terminate and then only allow the parent to accept for a new connection ?

Comment: @Chaitanya Yes. However there are other functions (like `waitpid`, also in the link) which can be used that doesn't block the parent process like plain `wait` does. Read the manual page for information about how to do the non-blocking call.

Comment: While reaping child process is useful, why not doing so can lead to the problems asked in the question?

Comment: @Joachim Ok, in this case using non-blocking call would be a better option. But, i dont understand as to why we should give `wait()` anyways once `fork()` both are separate processes right? Actually child should just care about its job and terminate and parent process should continue. Am I correct in the understanding ?

Comment: @Chaitanya Added explanation of why `wait` is needed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes very much correct. I agree. But, in this even if we do not give the `wait()` the child process should stop right ? Thats where I am confused :) . (But, still the child is running.)

Comment: @Chaitanya If the child has called `exit` or returned from its "main" function, it's not running. It's still in the process table though, in a "zombie" state.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ok. Actually I gave a `print` statement above the `accept()` method. Once the first request was served, the `print` statement got executed twice. It means two processes were waiting for accepting connections. I checked the state of it using the command give above it was showing as `sleeping`. Even if it is zombie state it should not run, but it was. Sorry, but still i am in a state of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

First of all thanks everyone for helping me out. I got the mistake in my code. :)

The problem was once after accepting the connection and forking, within the child process I got to `close()` the socket connection using the file descriptor used in accept method like

```
accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
```

then `close(sockfd)` should be called within the child process. Since, it was not being closed in the child process, the socket was alive for `accept()` connections. So, nevertheless `_exit()` was given the child process won't be terminated until the associated socket file descriptor is closed.

along with this within the parent process we got to call `wait()` or `waitpid()` depending on your need for the child process to be removed from the process table and avoiding its zombie state.